# TabLayout displays unwanted "borders"

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I'm using TabLayout, and I'm getting these weird borderlines and I can't tell why.

I'm talking about those diagonal ones in grey coming from the sides - how can I remove them?

[image: Screen]

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.smt.smt.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill">

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"/>

</FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Style being used as this activity theme**

```
<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Looks like rotation more than borders

Comment: provide code related

Comment: @AntonShkurenko what do you mean by "rotation"? Please elaborate what part of the code you need to see